# wireframe overlay on Collada textures - three.js

Tags: textures, collada, three.js, wireframe

When I use a Collada model with .jpg texture, three.js seems to overlay a wireframe mesh over the texture. 
My question - is there a way to remove the wireframes?

an example is here;
http://movealpha.com/dae/test1.html

and this is the same example with the Collada texture removed to show the underlying wireframe;
http://movealpha.com/dae/test2.html

**Is this an issue or is there a simple way to remove the wireframe overlay?**

ps. Thanks mrDoob for a truly AWESOME javascript library - we are collectively not worthy!

Answer (score 0):

mrdoob answered this on github;
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/885

here's a copy of his answer

> It's a limitation of CanvasRenderer. Setting material.overdraw = true
>   may improve things. You can find the object that has the material you
>   want to change by doing:

```
var object = collada.scene.getChildByName( 'object_name', true );
object.material.overdraw = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by setting material.overdraw=0.5 for all(!) children in collada.scene. In my case there were children inside children.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load( 'model.dae', function ( collada ) {
var dae = collada.scene;
for (var i=0; i<dae.children.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<dae.children[i].children.length; j++) {
            dae.children[i].children[j].material.overdraw=0.5;
        }
    }
scene.add(dae);    
}
```